# how do I display the profile of any user?

Tags: django

Please I am a beginner in django, and I need help on how to make the profile of any user view-able by a currently logged in user by just clicking on the username. Have got no idea about this. see what have got :
**views**

```
def profile(request, username):
context = {
           'userprofile': User.objects.get(username=username),
           }
return render_to_response('profile.html',context)
```

**profile.html**

```
Name: {{ userprofile.get_full_name }}
Username: {{ userprofile.username }}
```

**urls**

```
url(r'^/profile/(?P<username>\w+)/$', auth(profile), {}, name='chat_history')
```

what I don't know is how apply this url on a username. As in this:

**home.html**

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {% if message.sender == user %}
            <p><a href="/profile/{{ xxxxx }}"> {{ message.sender }}</a> >
            <a href="/profile/{{ xxxxx }}/">{{ message.receiver }}</a> : <br/>
            {{ message.message }}
            <sub>{{ message.creation_date }}</sub>
                </p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Have got no idea what 'xxxxx' should be

Comment: do you know anything about django? its pretty standard url/view/template stuff

Comment: yes, I do know little things about django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `message.sender` is a User object, then `{{message.sender.username}}` should put the username into the URL.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#user-objects

Comment: thanks, that actually worked. But i have problem with returning HttpResponseRedirect to the profile page. As in something like this: